# Is there a way to keep an image from "floating" on the page when using img-fluid class?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

We've built a website using bootstrap. We're checking the responsiveness of the site and have encountered an issue with an image "floating" on top of the page when we inspect the page and go to toggle device toolbar and change the setting to "iPad." Our site functions as expected on the desktop, mobile (galaxy, iPhone x, etc), and even iPad Pro settings.

[image]

```css
.our-story {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #67b7f2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid pt-5">
  <div class="row our-story">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-1 mb-3">
      <h2 class="mt-5">We Move Lives</h2>
      <p>Our process begins with asking a lot of questions and listening to your needs and concerns. Then we survey your entire home and assess everything that needs to be moved. We identify high-value, fragile items such as pianos, antiques, paintings, and chandeliers that will require special care. Finally, we create a detailed  schedule for packing,  loading, and delivery.</p>
      <a href="about-us.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-tosa">Our Story</button></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="img/steve-justin-bruce-standup.png" class="img-fluid mt-5">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: This is our design from Photoshop]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by floating since it's not apparent from the image or the html, is there a reproducible example? Quick things that stand out are the `col-md-6 offset-md-1` + `col-md-4` = 11 when it should total 12, and they only apply on the `md` breakpoints, the `img-fluid` just sets `max-width: 100%; height: auto` to scale the img to parent so I'm just guessing it may just be a grid issue but I'm not seeing it in the example provided sorry.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your reply. What I mean by "floating" is that you can see that the image has been cropped and is floating on the blue background when we want the bottom of the image (the mens legs) to be flush with the bottom of the blue container. I have updated the original post to show our design from photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok, so yea I'd suggest something more like this, notice the margin -> padding changes and the `flex-end` on the img container cell. Without giving the image some sort of a bottom anchor it's just doing as expected.

Oh and embedding a `button` in an `a`nchor is no bueno, Cheers

```css
.our-story {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #67b7f2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row our-story">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-2 pb-3 pt-5">
      <h2>We Move Lives</h2>
      <p>Our process begins with asking a lot of questions and listening to your needs and concerns. Then we survey your entire home and assess everything that needs to be moved. We identify high-value, fragile items such as pianos, antiques, paintings, and chandeliers that will require special care. Finally, we create a detailed  schedule for packing,  loading, and delivery.</p>
      <a class="btn btn-outline-tosa" href="about-us.html">Our Story</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 d-flex flex-end justify-content-center pt-5">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```